# pairs queryset in django - the way to do it and the optimal db structure?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model structure like that:

```
class Family:
    ...

class Person:
   role = models.CharField(choices=['husband', 'wife'])
   family= ForeignKey(to=Family)
   investment = models.IntegerField()
   ... # bunch of other fields here relevant for queries
```

I need to do a lot of queries that would involve group operations. For instance *`get total investment per family and separate investments for husband and wife`*.

So the resulting table would look like:

```
Family   Husband    Husb.Investment  Wife   Wife.Investment   TotalFamilyInvestment
1          1            10000         2       20000                  30000
2          3            25000         4       1000                   26000
```

While `TotalFamilyInvestment` is not a problem, just a `Sum` over `family.persons.all()`, I can't figure out how effectively plug in the same queryset 'husband' and 'wife' amounts, without just looping stupidly through each 'Family' instance requesting its persons filtered by `role` and retrieving its `investment` (or other) values.

Another question/solution would be just to re-do the db structure like that:

```
class Person:
   role = models.CharField(choices=['husband', 'wife'])
   investment = models.IntegerField()
   ... # bunch of other fields here relevant for queries

class Family:
   husband = models.OneToOneField(to=Person, related_name='husband_family')
   wife = models.OneToOneField(to=Person, related_name='wife_family')
```

That would solve the issue above, but it would create other problems (for instance this ugly way of to 1to1 fields pointing to `Person` model. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I would filter a query by role and sum the investments for each to get the investment for husbands and wives in return

```
def get_investments(request):
    husband_investment = Family.objects
        .filter(Person__role='husband')
        .aggregate(Sum('investment'))
    [...]
    return(husband_investment)
```